# MSword spellcheck: ignore text between this and that

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, spell-check, grammar

How can I set a spellcheck rule that will enable MSword (2013) to skip some part of the text.

For instance I would ask him to skip the text between a double parenthesis.

> text that must be checked here ((skip that part)) and here.

Is it possible to do it with VBA?

ps: This [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/626773/make-microsoft-word-spellcheck-ignore-square-brackets) does not answer the question. (What the guy was asking was more tricky: he wanted the spellcheck to ignore some characters with a word eg. "blabla correct[ing] blabla")

Comment: Unfortunately, that linked thread does answer the question: there's no inbuilt way to do that in Word.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 what the guy was asking was more tricky, he wanted the spellcheck to ignore some characters such as "correct[ing]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

1. You need to set a new style that will not be checked, to apply it to the existing text: this is explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/148055/how-to-ignore-spelling-and-grammar-for-certain-text-styles-in-word-2007?rq=1)
2. Select the text you don't want to be corrected : use the following regex (Find and replace and check use wildcards) to select everything between your `(( ))` :  `\(\(\.*\)\)`
3. Click on format, style and choose the style created in 1.
4. Click on Replace All
5. Next time you enter a  text between a double parenthesis apply the style

You can assign a shorcut to the style by right clicking on the style in the ribbon Home/style and choosing Modify. Than click on format, Shorcut key and choose an unassigned combination.